# Creating sub-folders in Caching, Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, caching

I have a Cache folder in tmp. 
I want a sub-folder in the cache folder, to store cache files of a particular page **ONLY** in that folder.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find bootstrap.php in your app/config

Replace the following lines

```
Cache::config('users_cache', array( // users_cache is the custom cache log name
  'engine' => File,
  'prefix' => 'cake_',  
  'path' => CACHE . 'users' . DS, // added sub-directory in users in tmp/cache
  'serialize' => true,
  'duration' => '+360 minutes'
));
```

Now, create a directory  in your **app/tmp/cache/users**

Then use it as the following format

```
Cache::write('enter_name', $users,'users_cache');
```

For best reference read the following article  [Cache::write](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#Cache::write)